# longitudes look flipped when displaying geoserver kml on google maps

Tags: geoserver, google-maps, kml, kmz

Any ideas on how to get my raster overlay lined up properly on google maps? The geoserver layer is re-projected from EPSG:4269 to 3857 before serving it to google maps. To me it looks as if the longitudes are flipped.

Here is my [code snippet and output on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffswitzer/wrc6sq4g/).

Here is the javascript:

```
function display_kmlmap() {
  var map_options = {};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

  var kmlUrl = 'http://geoserver.usanpn.org/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=wms&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&format=kml&layers=si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism&styles=leafout&height=1000&width=1000&transparent=true&bbox=-125.02083333333302,24.06249999929686,-66.479166666662,49.937499999073005&srs=EPSG:4326';
  var kmlOptions = {
    map: map
  };

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
}
```

and html:

```
<body onload="display_kmlmap()">
  Testing SI-X kml overlay.
  <br/>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px; float:left">
  </div>
</body>
```

And a screenshot:
[image]

Here is a geoserver screenshot of my layer crs reprojection and bounding box:
[image]

Here is the KML file as produced by geoserver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Document>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-101.29187627494827</longitude>
            <latitude>40.68941860702888</latitude>
            <altitude>6884659.870044568</altitude>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <tilt>0.0</tilt>
            <range>5563166.286905736</range>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <Folder>
            <name>si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-101.29187627516126</longitude>
                <latitude>40.689418607858016</latitude>
                <altitude>6884659.869997282</altitude>
                <heading>0.0</heading>
                <tilt>0.0</tilt>
                <range>5563166.286867525</range>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <GroundOverlay>
                <name>si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism</name>
                <drawOrder>0</drawOrder>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://geoserver.usanpn.org:80/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=wms&amp;request=GetMap&amp;version=1.1.1&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;layers=si-x%3Azabelli_bloom_prism&amp;styles=leafout&amp;height=1433&amp;width=768&amp;transparent=true&amp;bbox=-125.02083333333302%2C24.06249999929686%2C-66.479166666662%2C49.937499999073005&amp;srs=EPSG%3A4326</href>
                    <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                    <viewRefreshMode>never</viewRefreshMode>
                    <viewRefreshTime>0.0</viewRefreshTime>
                    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
                </Icon>
                <altitude>0.0</altitude>
                <LatLonBox>
                    <north>49.937499999073005</north>
                    <south>24.06249999929686</south>
                    <east>-125.02083333333302</east>
                    <west>-66.479166666662</west>
                    <rotation>0.0</rotation>
                </LatLonBox>
            </GroundOverlay>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

If I edit the KML file and swap the values for east and west like so:

```
<LatLonBox>
<north>49.937499999073005</north>
<south>24.06249999929686</south>
<east>-66.479166666662</east>
<west>-125.02083333333302</west>
<rotation>0.0</rotation>
</LatLonBox>
```

and point Google Maps to the edited KML file then the raster overlays correctly. However, I don't want to manually edit the KML files.

**Update (Aug 24, 2017)** - Never did figure this out and we ended up not using kml to deliver these maps. I will point out that this server is currently running geoserver version 2.10.1.

Comment: Please put useful code and a screenshot in the question body, so that folks who won't (or can't) follow links aren't excluded from answering.  This way the question can't be broken if a different site goes dark.

Comment: Please post the extents and coordinate system of your raster. Is it georeferenced?

Comment: Are you sure that the bbox parameter of your kmlURL is in the right order?

Comment: @AndreJ They are listed as minx,miny,maxx,maxy.
&bbox=-125.02083333333302,24.06249999929686,-66.479166666662,49.937499999073005  The problem is that minx is getting mapped to east and maxx is getting mapped to west, but since they are both negative this should be reversed. Is there a way to flip the mapping?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you found a solution? I'm using geoserver 2.7.2

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75588)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75588)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be a GeoServer bug on creating the KML.

I can see that a GetMap request with image/png output works:

http://geoserver.usanpn.org/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&layers=si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism&styles=&WIDTH=786&HEIGHT=348&bbox=-125.02083333333302,24.06249999929686,-66.479166666662,49.937499999073005&srs=epsg:4326&FORMAT=image/png&

(I changed the width and height values to avoid distortion)

So asking for KML (I think the correct MIME type for the format is `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`) as below should work, but as you say the West and East bounds are swapped.

[http://geoserver.usanpn.org/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&layers=si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism&styles=&WIDTH=786&HEIGHT=348&bbox=-125.02083333333302,24.06249999929686,-66.479166666662,49.937499999073005&srs=epsg:4326&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&](http://geoserver.usanpn.org/geoserver/si-x/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.1.1&layers=si-x:zabelli_bloom_prism&styles=&WIDTH=786&HEIGHT=348&bbox=-125.02083333333302,24.06249999929686,-66.479166666662,49.937499999073005&srs=epsg:4326&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml%20xml&)